# 顔認識のプログラムが何をしているのかよく分からないです

Tags: python, 画像, 画像処理

とても抽象的でごめんなさい。
今、熱画像から顔を検出しようということで、以下のサイト(GitHub)にあるpythonのプログラム一式をダウンロードしてみました。
https://github.com/Alpkant/Thermal-to-Visible-Face-Recognition-Using-Deep-Autoencoders

READMEも読んであらかたやっていることは今回の目的と一致しているなということまでは分かったのですが、なんか具体的に何をしているのかよく分からなかったです。

熱画像はすでに準備してあるので後はそれを読み込んで顔を検出したいのですが、
どのプログラムを実行すればいいのかとか、データセットをどうやって使うのかが分からなくて..。
調べようにも何て調べたらいいのかって感じなので何かアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが、OpenCVは検討されましたでしょうか？顔認識が目的であれば、こちらが簡単だと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます! 以前opencvを用いた手法で調べたところ、一般的なカラー画像に対する顔認識のことなら結構出てくるのですが、熱画像に対して顔認識をするというのが調べても出てこなくてなかなか進まない状況です...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> READMEも読んであらかたやっていることは今回の目的と一致

されているようなので、こんなことは百も承知だと思われますが。一応。

ご呈示のエントリは論文の検証用ネットワークを見せるためのエントリで、直接使える形ではないように見受けられます。（むろん使うことは可能ですが）、学習済みの重み情報などが提示されていないので自分で訓練させる必要がありそうです。
すでにラベル情報はあるようですがもとになっている画像ファイルを特定し持ってこなければなりません。概要を読むとCarl Datasetsに対応したAnnotationを用意しているようなので、そのデータを取ってきましょう。利用できるようになるまではざっくり以下の通りだと思います。

- 訓練データとテストデータをラベル付きで用意する。
- データをU-Netに渡せる形に加工するプログラムを作る
- 訓練させる
- 結果を確認する。
- ハイパーパラメータを調整する
- 以上を繰り返していいモデルができるまで頑張る

参考までに、DataSetsは読み込み用のクラスが既に用意されていて、これも使い方がcodes/README.mdに記載があるので、参照してください。

Comment: さっそく画像ファイルを入手するために以下のサイトでCarl Database の人に申請書をメールで送り、無事ダウンロードすることができた..とここまではよかったのですが、ダウンロードしたファイルの中にある画像の名前と今回の学習に使っている画像の名前が一致しませんでした。どこから取ってくればいいでしょうか...  http://splab.cz/en/download/databaze/carl-database

Comment: このリポジトリの作成者にも問い合わせたところ、どうやらデータセットの作成者がフォルダ名などを変更してしまったようです

Comment: 素晴らしい行動力だと思います。あと、追加情報ありがとうございます。